# Cannot resolve method getlatitude()

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I am new to programming and am following the Google Location API tutorial. I have followed all the steps properly, however, the following code gives me error at getlatitude() and getlongitude(). Error: Cannot resolve method getlatitude(). Would be great if someone could point to the issue. One more thing to note, the code seems to never use the android.location.Location class and I hoped the getlatitude() will come from there.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import android.location.Location;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /**
     * Represents a geographical location.
     */
    protected String mLastLocation;
    protected static final String TAG = "basic-location-sample";
    protected TextView mLatitudeText;
    protected TextView mLongitudeText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mLatitudeText = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.latitude_text));
        mLongitudeText = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.longitude_text));
        buildGoogleApiClient();
   }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener((OnConnectionFailedListener) this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

        mLastLocation = String.valueOf(LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient));
       if (mLastLocation!= null) {
            mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
       }
 }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the type of `mLastLocation`:

```
protected String mLastLocation;
```

`String` doesn't have `getLatitude` and `getLongitude` methods. Your variable should be of type `Location`, and initialized without the `String.valueOf` call:

```
protected Location mLastLocation;
...
mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch; I now understand how this ought to work. I am at the risk of abusing this thread; the code works but I am still unable to have my Latitude and Longitude co-ordinates displayed. I suspect that mLatitude and mLongitude are not getting updated in the OnConnected part. Is there a way to check if a connection is actually established?

Comment: @Rehan: No idea, I'm afraid - I'm not an Android dev. But I suspect if you search on existing questions here on Stack Overflow, you'll find plenty of related ones.

Comment: I'll look into existing posts for that. Thanks again for helping with the Location issue :)